# Is there a way to click on selected object on jubula?

Tags: eclipse, automated-tests, jubula

I'm using Jubula to automate a JavaFX application. The problem is that, when I selected a tabbed component, I want to click right on this component. However, this component isn't mapped cause I selected it with index.

Is there a way to click on it with the right button?

Answer (score 0):

If the mouse in in the component, Jubula does not change the position for the next action(except it is specified in the action).

This means if you select the tab with the select tab action. You could do another action e.g. "select context menu" at the exact same position.